# module 'parsedatetime.pdt_locales' has no attribute 'de_DE'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to compile my python script into exe using pyinstaller. It came out successful. But when I try to run the exe file, it shows an error with **parsedatetime** module.

I'm using Python 3.8.3. Please help. Thank you very much.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "trendy.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 623, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\parsedatetime\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "site-packages\parsedatetime\__init__.py", line 69, in <listcomp>
  File "site-packages\parsedatetime\pdt_locales\__init__.py", line 29, in load_locale
AttributeError: module 'parsedatetime.pdt_locales' has no attribute 'de_DE'
```

Comment: Have you tried importing parsedatetime.pdt_locales explicitly in your script?  The way parsedatetime imports it might not be recognized by pyinstaller.

Also, you probably want to be a little more explicit with your question.  What platform are you running on?  What command did you use to create your executable?  Can you slim down your script to a minimal example that displays the problem?